# Performance issue for WPF application when is running without right clicking and choosing "Run as administrator"

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF application which will be used on tablets with Windows 10.
In my development environment, the application runs very fast. However, if I run the application on tablet without admin rights, the application responds very slow : all animations are slow, the scrolling is not smooth, and touch problems are visible (cannot move the caret). If the application has admin rights all things are working fine.

I tried to disable the logs, I tried to decrease the FPS, nothing seems to help.
My application is connected to a sqlite database, but even without accessing the database is very slow. There are no other connections that may require admin rights.
What could be the problem?

**EDIT:** Also in my dev environment the app is running slower without admin rights. I was running the VS2015 with admin rights and for that reason the application worked fine.

Comment: Can you profile the app twice, once with admin rights, and once without. This might hopefully help reduce where in your code the issue is coming from

Comment: I've tried to use remote profiler, but the rendering is very slow without admin, and parsing.

Comment: Please tell Framework-Version and Target-Platform (x86/x64)

Comment: Thank you for your time. The app is developed under .NET Framework 4.6.1 and is targeting all types of platforms (Any CPU)

Comment: Some stuff to read and try: [First](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20906195/wpf-low-performance-when-process-is-executed-under-system-account), [Second](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2947118/wpf-slow-to-start-on-x64-in-net-framework-4-0). This seems to match your issue

Comment: I saw that answers. For the first, my app is running always under a user with admin rights, never under SYSTEM, and right now, I will try the second approach.

Comment: No, still no change. It works very slow on x86. I've updated the NGEN also...

Comment: There's no magic bullet. Please develop your answer with profiler tests. What are the differences in those tests between admin vs non admin?

Comment: I think you need to add a manifest file to your project and set level to `requireAdministrator`.

Comment: I think the problem comes from your database queries. Are you on a domain? Are you on a local machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To offer an answer for people that might face the same issue, now, after I've searched a lot for something helpful, I can say that this problem it is mainly a problem related to rights. 
   If you encounter this issue, try to run Visual Studio **without** admin rights and try to isolate the region where the application begins to act very slow (or the place were it crashes) . In my case, wasn't the database, or the log files, but a file in *AppData* which was used by an external assembly. I've seen that, every time that dll was called, the application was freezing and using *dotTrace*, I've managed to find which file it is used. After setting the rights (r/w) on that file, everything was back to normal.

Answer (score 2):

WPF has settings under HKEY_CURRENT_USER that can disable hardware acceleration:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970912(v=vs.110).aspx

If the Disable Hardware Acceleration Option or the Use Reference Rasterizer Option are set, a WPF application will run slowly for that user.

Comment: Wooh, thats weird, but makes sense. Never heard of that. Good to know

Comment: These options are set correctly on my PC, but if I use "Disable Hardware Acceleration", that application gives an error which is a little bit strange : "Cannot access external driver"

Comment: Stating from that error, I've found out that one of the drivers that I've used needs rights on a file which is placed on AppData. After I've set the full rights for that file, the application immediately started to work well. I will give you the bounty, because was the answer that helped me, even though the settings that you proposed were in place. Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1):

Try to trace your app with [Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor.aspx). Run 2 traces for app running with and without admin rights. Filter your app events only via `Tools->Process Tree... -> right click on your process -> Add to Include filter` and compare these trace logs (or just post them here). Pay attention on gaps between registry key readings or network access.

That literally could be anything. 
Mark Russinovich make a presentation almost every year about finding some interesting cases. [Here's one of them](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U0yk2a04mbs).

P.S. I'm sorry to post that as an answer, but I don't have enough points to add comments right now.